# Realize switching function using only 2/4 decoders and logic gates

Tags: logic-gates, decoder

I am given the function $$f(A, B, C, D) = CD + A'B + BD'$$

The question states realize it using only 2-to-4  decoders and logic gates (if needed). My approach:

Use 3 2-to-4 decoders, one with inputs C and D, one with A and B, and one with inputs B and D. Take the output which satisfies $$CD, A'B, BD'$$ respectively and then combine them using an OR gate to get the function I needed. Is this method correct, and if not, what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> Use 3 2-to-4 decoders, one with inputs C and D, one with A and B, and one with inputs B and D. Take the output which satisfies
>   CD,A′B,BD′
>   respectively and then combine them using an OR gate to get the function I needed

This is indeed a correct implementation and is as shown in the diagram above.